# PhpStorm .idea in GIT issues

Tags: git, phpstorm

In order to keep codestyles the same for every team member, our projects have PhpStorm config files as a part of GIT.

**Conditions**

VCS contains config files in .idea. Files list:

- `codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml`
- `sqldialects.xml`
- `inspectionProfiles/Project_defaults.xml`;

**Problems**

- The project root directory is shown empty;
- Indexation problems (the indexation process never finishes)
- Trees display errors (files are not shown in some directories, always "loading files...")

**Workaround**

If I delete the entire `.idea` folder with the files in it and PhpStorm reinitializes the settings, everything seemingly works fine.

Have anyone else encountered something similar?
What can you recommend?

Comment: was all files in .idea folder on the git? or do you ignore some files?

Comment: Only the listed files are on git. The rest of them are ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that the known problem when `.idea` folder is present and not empty but does not have minimal needed files (cannot say for sure, but I guess the IDE wants to see `workspace.xml` and maybe `*.iml` + `modules.xml` to avoid this issue).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271728 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on the progress.

---

> What can you recommend?

Sadly I've got nothing significant to suggest from my end. I simply do not face such problem (can easily manually workaround it if needed).

The only thing I may suggest is:

- Make a new project without `.idea` folder in it.
- Once the project is created, close it in the IDE and overwrite those files (a simple copy-paste will do just fine).

Comment: Sorry, just want to clarify, `workspace.xml` and other files that listed on my answer are not minimal needed files. I added them to `.gitignore`  on a lot of projects and never had any issue.

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur You are correct, and JetBrains themselves tell what files should not be VCS tracked (e.g. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839) but somehow this causes issues for certain users. The "minimal needed files" is my best guess to have a "project" in the IDE-eyes -- they way how I understand it + comments from that ticket.

Comment: I just tested your second guess is right, `projectname.iml` and `modules.xml` are the "minimal needed files`. Without both my files, the project root directory is shown empty like the OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore all user-specific config files. Below is the recommended file list that should be added to the `.gitignore`

```
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio, WebStorm and Rider
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf

# AWS User-specific
.idea/**/aws.xml

# Generated files
.idea/**/contentModel.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml

# Gradle
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Gradle and Maven with auto-import
# When using Gradle or Maven with auto-import, you should exclude module files,
# since they will be recreated, and may cause churn.  Uncomment if using
# auto-import.
# .idea/artifacts
# .idea/compiler.xml
# .idea/jarRepositories.xml
# .idea/modules.xml
# .idea/*.iml
# .idea/modules
# *.iml
# *.ipr

# CMake
cmake-build-*/

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Cursive Clojure plugin
.idea/replstate.xml

# SonarLint plugin
.idea/sonarlint/

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

# Editor-based Rest Client
.idea/httpRequests

# Android studio 3.1+ serialized cache file
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser
```

If some files are still on the git, you should delete them and then commit them.

reference:
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/JetBrains.gitignore

Comment: The problem is that the committed list of the files we have is not a part of this list already.

Comment: @MaxShaian So you should add other files besides the above list. Because some files are needed as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: The thing is that those files contain individualized settings and it's up to a developer to decide how they should look. Such as phpunit settings or autoimport settings. They can work on different environments.

Comment: @MaxShaian PHPUnit settings are on outside .idea folder, and auto import setting and other user-specific settings are mostly in `workspace.xml ` and it's already on above list, so it's should be ignored using .gitignore.

Comment: My experiments say that if I leave out the aforementioned files, but keep the other ones, I still experience the problems.

Comment: @MaxShaian But in a lot of projects I did it and never had any problems. And no other programmer complains about something like your issue in the question..